# Checking database for NULL boolean value

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, boolean

I have a field in a table that is boolean, a range of records have no value (not true or false). How do I write my SQL statement to find these?

I have tried the following SQL statements without success:

```
1) SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = NULL
2) SELECT * FROM table WHERE field != TRUE AND field != FALSE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks, Ben

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, esp/ Mitch Wheat :)

Comment: NULL is not a value, it's absence of value. Thus no value could be compared to the absence of value.

Comment: @Milen: Pretty much every other language manages this just fine. IMO it's extremely dumb that SQL needs a different operator for this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In TSQL, you need to use `IS` rather than `=` when comparing with `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
select * from table where field IS null
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `IS NULL` I believe:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NULL
```